# How do I make page reload and clear input values after pressing the button in the contact form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

*Note that I have little experience with PHP and js and even if I may need to use them, some extra guidance in implementing those codes may be needed

I've been working on a contact form recently and things have been going well except that I have no idea how to make the page refresh, or at least the input values to reset itself.

As-is now, the PHP has an "echo" thing that tells whether the form was submitted or not. But I can always just turn back to the page and the input values are still there. I want them to clear.

```html
<form method="post" action="contactform.php">

  <p class="contact-top">Name:
    <br /><input name="name" /></p>

  <p>Your email:
    <br /><input name="email" /></p>

  <!-- Important: if you add any fields to this page, you will also need to update the php script -->

  <p class="antispam">Leave this empty:
    <br /><input name="url" /></p>

  <p>Your message:
    <br /><textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></p>

  <p><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p>

</form>
```

Comment: after submission success reset the array `$_POST = array();`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

This kind of things nowadays are made in JS, where you add a layer of validation in frontend, but this is the old html way.